# Prime Palindrome programme on Codeeval

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie and have only today began exploring Codeeval. I wrote the below program to find the largest prime palindrome smaller than 1000:-

```
class PrimePalindrome 
{

    public static boolean is_prime(int num)
    {
        boolean chck_prime = false;
        for(int i = 2; i<= num/2; i++)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                chck_prime = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        return !chck_prime;
    }

    public static boolean is_palindrome(int num)
    {
        int rev = 0, original = num;
        int dig;

        while(num > 0)
        {
            dig = num %10;
            rev = rev*10+dig;
            num = num /10;
        }

        if(original == rev)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        boolean prime_check = false, palindraome_check = false, max_check= false;
        for(int i = 1000; i>1 ; i--)
        {

            if(is_prime(i) && is_palindrome(i))
            {

                System.out.println(i);
                max_check = true;
            }

            if(max_check)
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

This programme runs fine on my Eclipse IDE but when I submit the solution in Code eval, it gives me the error :-

Error: Could not find or load main class Main

What am I doing wrong? Initially I had set my class as public and it used to give me the below error :-

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx256m -Xms256m -Xss256k
/tmp/tmpZhpVMw/Main.java:1: error: class PrimePalindrome is public, should be declared in a file named PrimePalindrome.java
public class PrimePalindrome 
       ^
1 error
```

Seems to be some environmental issue, but I cant figure out what.Can someone help me figure out what's wrong in my program and why code eval wont compile it successfully?

Comment: Your classname is different then your filename: `class PrimePalindrome is public, should be declared in a file named PrimePalindrome`

Comment: *"Could not find or load main class Main"* ... it is obviously looking for a class named `Main`, so don't you think you should name your class `Main`?

Comment: @Tom.. yep just tried that and it worked...